# rviz config file for new urdf

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch it references https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/blob/master/rviz/urdf.rviz.

As I understand; that rviz file is tied to that urdf. So if I'm using my own urdf file do I need to follow http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html to get the correct rviz config?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358276/rviz-config-file-for-new-urdf/) by [bgraysea](https://answers.ros.org/users/56768/bgraysea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @bgraysea,

Tehcnically speaking that particular rviz config file is tied to that particular URDF since your topics, links, etc will be different in your new robot but you can still use that rviz config by changing the sources of every plugin that you can see in the left panel.

[Rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) is a visualization tool that works by adding displays to the interface. Hence you can start by launching an empty rviz config (E.g.: default) and then populate with displays by cliking in the left bottom button named `"Add"`. Form there you will able to add odometry, tf, robot model displays etc. and then change your source inputs from each one of them in the left panel to adjust them to your robot.

There is a nice user guide that explains this in depth. Take a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide).

Hope that helps you.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0